# Window Active Directory authentication for Intranet user and Forms authentication for Internet users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

How do i implement Window Active Directory authentication for Intranet user and Forms authentication for Internet users, i found many examples online explaining each of them individually but can't get to find one that explain both implemented together.

I have my ASP MVC 4 project working with Forms Authentication but was requested to add Windows Active Directory authenticate for intranet users. How do i do it?

My existing Forms Authentication

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"/>
    </authentication>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? It's 2016 and I still can't find a definitive answer to this! (And I've been searching for two days!)

Comment: @ScottK.Fraley I could not recall exactly how i resolve the above but I remember that upgraded my MVC project to MVC 5 and use AuthenticationManager to manage the logins (be in intra net or token). AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

Answer (score 2):

I am only just beginning to explore this type of situation myself so I am not going to try and give a definitive answer, but I think that you will want to start looking at Claims Based Authentication and Secure Token Services (STS)
Have a look at:

- [Least Privilege](http://leastprivilege.com/) by Dominick Baier; as well as some of his
- [pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Authors/Details/dominick-baier) courses to get a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve.